# IE6 anchor wordwrapping (display:block, width:0)

Tags: html, css, anchor, word-wrap

Unfortunaly this site we're developing has to be IE6 compatible. It contains a horizontal block style menu, but there's still one more problem with IE6.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a {
display: block;
width: 0px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">This is a anchor tag</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Because of the spaces, it wraps every word on a new line. What do I need to do if I want it on a single line only?

Thanks!

Comment: You explictely ask for a width of 0px ?  Why ? In compiant web programs, I would expect nothing to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css on the *a* element:

```
white-space: nowrap
```

Comment: that's really quite the hack, tho. setting width to 0 and forcing it to not wrap? i'd definitely go with not setting width *or* wrap and letting the browser allocate the required width to the anchor, based on its content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried popping your anchor into a span or div?

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't set its width to `0` would be the cross-browser proper approach.

Use `float: left` instead, if you want the anchor to be displayed in block mode but not allocate 100% width.

When you use floats like that, you also need to make sure you `clear` them, to make them occupy space in their container:

```
<div>
    <a ... />
    <a ... />
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The anchor tag already has float: left, but if I don't set it's width to 0 it automaticly resizes to 100%. It should, however, have the required with for the text.

Comment: it does not have float left from the code you've shown us, and it doesn't seem like it either, because an element that is floated does not automatically assume 100% width. for reference: http://jsbin.com/ozola/edit (click 'output' to see how that code is rendered)